# ResourceData[] - ResourceAcquire: This request requires authentication

Tags: curated-data, authentication, resourceobject

I am trying to follow some examples on the Mathematica website, e.g. https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/neural-networks/digit-classification.html?product=language

but I cannot get the functions ResourceObject[] or ResourceData[] to work.

```
in: ResourceData["Fireballs and Bolides"]
out: ResourceAcquire: This request requires authentication.
```

What do I need to authenticate and how? There is no mention of this, neither in the examples nor in the explanation of the functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before running the commands, one needs to sign into the cloud using one's WolframID credentials,

```
CloudConnect[userid, pwd]
```

Userid and/or pwd can be left if you want to be prompted.

Comment: I had the same problem on a new machine, even after signing in either via Help->Sign in or right at the start of _Mathematica_.

Comment: @b.gatessucks had or have? The CloudConnect[] solved it for me. If that does not work for you, I have no idea what could be wrong...

Comment: I had. I got past it, probably doing the same as you, but sadly I forgot what it was precisely.